# How to add Date Header to an WebRequest

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest, datetime-format, webrequest, gmt

I am trying to add a "**Date**" to an WebRequest Header.But it returns an error as "**The 'Date' header must be modified using the appropriate property or method.
Parameter name: name**".I need to pass an Date header to an request.

So I tried using HttpWebRequest,It has Date property.

But what is my problem is,I want to pass an GMT format value in an Date filed.I cant able to pass it because it is an DateTime variable.

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.Now.ToUniversalTime();
string date = string.Format("{0:r}", dt);//Thu, 11 Jan 2018 09:38:26 GMT
request.Date = date;//throws an error here.
```

Please give me a suggestion for how to pass an GMT format value to a DateTime variable or how to add Date header to an WebRequest.

Comment: request.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.Date, DateTime.Now.ToString() );

Comment: tried this ..Still getting the same error

Answer (score 0):

Doesnt this work?

```
request.Date = DateTime.UtcNow();
```

As per the documentation:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.httpwebrequest.date?view=netframework-4.7.1#System_Net_HttpWebRequest_Date

> The classes in the System.Net namespace always write it out the Date
>   property on the wire during transmission in standard form using GMT
>   (Utc) format.